# IIS 8.5 Credentials working for windows authentication but not for basic

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, http-basic-authentication, iis-8.5

I have an IIS 8.5 on a windows server 2012 machine. When I enable the windows authentication (basic authentication is disabled), I can access and see the home page of IIS (http://localhost) with the credentials of a LDAP user in the same domain. However, when I enable basic authentication (windows authentication is disabled), I cannot access the home page with the same credentials I used for windows (401 Unauthorized error).

The credentials I am using belong to a user (LDAP user) within the same domain as the windows server 2012 machine.

Why does only windows authentication work for those credentials and not basic authentication ?

Note: Eventually I plan to write restlet java code to post resources using basic authentication.